# How to import larger txt file into excel?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm new to VBA and I'm trying to import a large txt file in to excel. My text file has 695252 lines, but when I import, it gives me 695001. Can anyone help me with the same?

```
Sub txtfile()

    Dim fn As String
    Dim newb As Workbook

    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .Title = "Select the file"
        .Filters.Clear
        .Filters.Add "Text files only", "*.txt*"
        If .Show <> False Then
            fn = .SelectedItems(1)
        Else
            MsgBox "No file selected"
        End If
    End With
    Set newb = Workbooks.Open(fn)
    newb.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Copy ThisWorkbook.Sheets(3).Range("a1")
    newb.Close False

End Sub
```

Comment: where does the Error happen? Are the lines missing allready in the newwb or after you copied the data?

Comment: It'd be welcome to see the actual file

Comment: What kind of "lines"?  A story?  It could just be concatenating multiple lines, or skipping blanks, or CR/LF's.  Or is this a numbered list -- **Can you identify specific records that are missing?**  Special symbols or foreign characters?  Is there an error?  Also please see the [tour], and [ask] and especially [mcve], then [edit] your question to provide more info.

Comment: To give you a hand with "[mcve]" I'll [edit] your code sample to include only the relevant section, however this question can't be answered without more information about the source file.

Comment: Without knowing the structure of the file [...] I would suggest reading the text into an array via direct I/O. The [EOF-Function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/eof-function) is probably what you want.

Comment: This code doesn't give me any error message. It just copies the lines till 695001 instead of 695252. The data file includes both numeric and alpha numeric columns. Unfortunately, I can't share the actual file here. Considering the comments from Chrowno, can you share an example on how to get the text in to direct I/O and use of EOF and LOF functions? Also, if you can explain which line does what in your example will really helpful for me to understand.

Answer (score 0):

So, the difference is 251.  Ok, I think some of those 'lines' do no have carriage returns, or whatever is being used to move data to the next line.  Import that text file into Access.  How many lines do you get?  I'll bet it will be 695001.  Try that, and feed back.